# Do && and || take the same precedence in c#?

Tags: java, c#

At the moment I'm taking a C# course and the book I'm using says `&&` and `||` take the same precedence and only evaluate left to right.  I do remember, however, that in Java this was not true and `&&` took prescience over `||` if I'm not mistaken.  This seems odd that these two languages would differ in such a fundamental way, am I incorrect about either of these two or is this difference common?

If it does differ language to language could anyone quite experienced in the field, add a list of some common languages and how this precedence is applied

Comment: [I googled `C# precedence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). What did you google?

Comment: FWIW, *all* of the following languages give Logical-AND a *higher* precedence than Logical-OR: C, C++, C#, Java, Scala, Perl, Ruby, Python, JavaScript, PHP, VB/VB.NET, Delphi, SQL. However, some of the languages (but not Java or C#) have the same precedence for the *bitwise* operators (e.g. `&` and `|`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm looking at an MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) that indicates that C# is just like Java. && takes precedence over ||. It may be that your book is mistaken.

(h/t Robert Harvey for updated link.)

Comment: Newer spec is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx.  The one you linked is from 2003.

Answer (score 7):

No.  `&&` binds more tightly than `||`.  This is fairly standard among most languages I know of.  Generally `and` applies before `or`.

This fact allows you to write any boolean expression without parentheses.  See also: [canonical normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms)